# Paramiko SSH client is unable to unpack ED25519 key

Tags: python-3.x, ssh, paramiko, ed25519

I'm trying to use a keypair for the SSH connection to an SFTP server.

I am able to do so if I generate an RSA key via `ssh-keygen -t rsa`.

When I connect to the server via Paramiko, things work fine:

```py
    private_key = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file("/path/to/my/private/key")
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    print("Connecting.")
    client.connect(hostname="host.sftp.com", username="user", pkey=private_key)
    print("Connected.")
```

However, if I try to do this with a ED25519 key, I get the below error:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
```

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 235, in from_private_key_file
    key = cls(filename=filename, password=password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 55, in __init__
    self._from_private_key_file(filename, password)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 176, in _from_private_key_file
    self._decode_key(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 192, in _decode_key
    n, e, d, iqmp, q, p = self._uint32_cstruct_unpack(data, "iiiiii")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/paramiko/pkey.py", line 529, in _uint32_cstruct_unpack
    raise SSHException(str(e))
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: unpack requires a buffer of 4 bytes
```

I'm a bit at a loss here since googling around doesn't seem to yield any relevant solutions. Is this a bug within `paramiko`? It is an issue with how I am initializing my `SSHClient`? Or is it actually a theoretical issue (ie. the way ED25519 creates the key, it is not possible to read in via the low-level `unpack()` call)?

Comment: `paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file` reads RSA keys. To read an Ed25519 key use `paramiko.ed25519key.from_private_key_file`. (And at least 2.2.0.)

Comment: :facepalm. Wow. I feel like an idiot. Go ahead and write that as an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is Dave Thompson's comment as an answer to just close the loop on this:

`paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file` reads RSA keys. To read an Ed25519 key use `paramiko.Ed25519Key.from_private_key_file`. (And at least 2.2.0.)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, with `paramiko==2.7.1`: says `AttributeError: module 'paramiko.ed25519key' has no attribute 'from_private_key_file'`. Maybe it was removed again?

Comment: it's `paramiko.Ed25519Key.from_private_key_file`

Comment: @ShreevatsaR updated answer to reflect what RonanT said.

Answer (score 0):

My use case was dealing with unknown key types, which results in the same error.  My private key is user supplied and I would not know beforehand what format it would be in.  Figured I'd post in case others are searching for a similar solution. This method checks the key type using the [cryptography library](https://cryptography.io/) and returns the corresponding Paramiko PKey.

```py
from io import StringIO
from paramiko import RSAKey, Ed25519Key, ECDSAKey, DSSKey, PKey
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization as crypto_serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import ed25519, dsa, rsa, ec

def from_private_key(file_obj, password=None) -> PKey:
    private_key = None
    file_bytes = bytes(file_obj.read(), "utf-8")
    try:
        key = crypto_serialization.load_ssh_private_key(
            file_bytes,
            password=password,
        )
        file_obj.seek(0)
    except ValueError:
        key = crypto_serialization.load_pem_private_key(
            file_bytes,
            password=password,
        )
        if password:
            encryption_algorithm = crypto_serialization.BestAvailableEncryption(
                password
            )
        else:
            encryption_algorithm = crypto_serialization.NoEncryption()
        file_obj = StringIO(
            key.private_bytes(
                crypto_serialization.Encoding.PEM,
                crypto_serialization.PrivateFormat.OpenSSH,
                encryption_algorithm,
            ).decode("utf-8")
        )
    if isinstance(key, rsa.RSAPrivateKey):
        private_key = RSAKey.from_private_key(file_obj, password)
    elif isinstance(key, ed25519.Ed25519PrivateKey):
        private_key = Ed25519Key.from_private_key(file_obj, password)
    elif isinstance(key, ec.EllipticCurvePrivateKey):
        private_key = ECDSAKey.from_private_key(file_obj, password)
    elif isinstance(key, dsa.DSAPrivateKey):
        private_key = DSSKey.from_private_key(file_obj, password)
    else:
        raise TypeError
    return private_key
```